# Need to add tabindex (with a walker?) to Wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, tabindex

I'm trying to retrofit a theme to be ADA Accessible and am having a really hard time making the dropdown menus show up when tabbed. I thought that adding tabindex would do the trick and have tried using a walker to do this but it keeps throwing errors. I'm looking for a solution to this if anyone can please help!

Thank you.

This is the walker code I was trying:

```
<?php
class WP_Custom_Nav_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

/**
 * Start the element output.
 *
 * @see Walker::start_el()
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
 * @param object $item   Menu item data object.
 * @param int    $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
 * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_nav_menu()
 * @param int    $id     Current item ID.
 */
public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

    $args->items_wrap = '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>';

    /**
     * Filter the CSS class(es) applied to a menu item's list item element.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
     *
     * @param array  $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
     * @param object $item    The current menu item.
     * @param array  $args    An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
     * @param int    $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     */
    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

    /**
     * Filter the ID applied to a menu item's list item element.
     *
     * @since 3.0.1
     * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
     *
     * @param string $menu_id The ID that is applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
     * @param object $item    The current menu item.
     * @param array  $args    An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
     * @param int    $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     */
    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li  tabindex="0" ' . $id . $class_names .'>';

    $atts = array();
    $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
    $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
    $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
    $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

    /**
     * Filter the HTML attributes applied to a menu item's anchor element.
     *
     * @since 3.6.0
     * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
     *
     * @param array $atts {
     *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's `<a>` element, empty strings are ignored.
     *
     *     @type string $title  Title attribute.
     *     @type string $target Target attribute.
     *     @type string $rel    The rel attribute.
     *     @type string $href   The href attribute.
     * }
     * @param object $item  The current menu item.
     * @param array  $args  An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
     * @param int    $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     */
    $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

    $attributes = '';
    foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
        if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
            $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
            $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
        }
    }

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a tabindex="-1" '. $attributes .'>';
    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */


    $item_output .= apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;


    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    /**
     * Filter a menu item's starting output.
     *
     * The menu item's starting output only includes `$args->before`, the opening `<a>`,
     * the menu item's title, the closing `</a>`, and `$args->after`. Currently, there is
     * no filter for modifying the opening and closing `<li>` for a menu item.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $item_output The menu item's starting HTML output.
     * @param object $item        Menu item data object.
     * @param int    $depth       Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param array  $args        An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
     */
    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}

}
```

Comment: Please provide the code or even better, a jsfiddle :)

Comment: Oops! Should have done that, I'm not used to posting here :) This is the site: https://sf1-dev.temp-net.com/

I added the walker code to my original post!